# How to read posted Json string from another page and assign them to controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am developing a website by using ASP.NET. I have a page where user can put advertisements. So after user fills the required fields I am redirect them to another page to review. In that page I am temporally shows what user has entered. So if they wrong they can go back or else can confirm.
So I avoid using sessions to pass the data to another page because it has a cost to the server. Also these data are not critical.
So I am put them in a Json string and post them.

Here what I have tried.

```
        JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Ad = new AdDetails.Ad();
        Ad.ContinentIdRef = byte.Parse(ddContinent.SelectedValue);
        Ad.ContinentName = ddContinent.SelectedItem.Text;
        Ad.CountryIdRef = byte.Parse(ddCountry.SelectedValue);
        Ad.CountryName = ddCountry.SelectedItem.Text;
        Ad.CityIdRef = UInt16.Parse(ddCity.SelectedValue);
        Ad.CityName = ddCity.SelectedItem.Text;
        //......
        string jsonString = json.Serialize(Ad);
```

My button code is

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCheckAd" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="Check My Add" CssClass="btn btn-success" Width="130" OnClick="btnCheckAd_Click" PostBackUrl="~/CheckAd.aspx" />
```

So now I want to retrieve this Json string from CheckAd.aspx and read those values to set labels and textboxes values. So how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
System.Text.Encoding encoding = Request.ContentEncoding;
using (var inputStream = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream,encoding))
{
  strJSON = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
}

JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
object serJsonDetails = javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(strJSON, typeof(object));
```

Comment: Thank you Ganesh. I almost got it. strJSON got the Json string correctly. But at the end of the line it throws an error saying "Invalid JSON primitive: ctl00." Also I tried like this adObject = javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<AdDetails.Ad>(jsonString); adObject is a instant of a class. But it also throws the same error. Also I found that Json string that catch from my destination page is difference than my source page.